# Mobile Filling Half Screen Only

Tags: android, html, ios, css, twitter-bootstrap

I've looked for similar questions on here, and although I have come across a few, I am not seeing any answers. I'm running into an issue where my desktop site is working well. I have designed it on bootstrap and it is fully responsive on there. When I look at it on any mobile phone, the navbar fills the top of the screen, however the content below, only fills half the screen. I'm really uncertain what I am missing here. If anyone can help with this I would greatly appreciate it. The site I have everything hosted on at the moment, is www.high-maintenance.us

```css
/* Custom Css */
/* Layout */

head {
  font-family: "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, "Lucida Grande", sans-serif;
  font-weight: 300;
}

body {
  font-family: "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, "Lucida Grande", sans-serif;
  font-weight: 300;
}

.textcenter {
  text-align: center;
}

.hide {
  display: none;
}

.index1 {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 1;
}

.index2 {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 2;
}

.index3 {
  z-index: 3;
}

.index4 {
  z-index: 4;
}

.index5 {
  z-index: 5;
}

.four {
  min-width: 320px !important;
}

.height350 {
  height: 350px;
}

.eighty {
  width: 80%;
  position: relative;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.smallcaps {
  font-variant: small-caps;
}

.allcaps {
  text-transform: uppercase;
}

.mobileShow {
  display: none;
}
/* Smartphone Portrait and Landscape */

@media only screen and (min-device-width: 320px) and (max-device-width: 480px) {
  .mobileShow {
    display: inline;
  }
}

.mobileHide {
  display: inline;
}
/* Smartphone Portrait and Landscape */

@media only screen and (min-device-width: 320px) and (max-device-width: 480px) {
  .mobileHide {
    display: none;
  }
}
/* End Layout */
/* Slider Start */

.result {
  border: none;
  background: none;
  font-size: 50px;
  font-style: italic;
  color: #E40412;
  font-weight: 700;
  font-family: HelveticaNeueBlackCondensed !important;
  float: right;
  position: relative !important;
  text-align: left !important;
  padding-bottom: 8px;
  margin-left: 165px;
  margin-top: -64px;
}

.opttitle {
  font-size: 26px;
  font-weight: 400 !important;
  font-family: HelveticaNeueBlackCondensed !important;
  color: #667;
  margin: auto !important;
  padding: 0 !important;
}

.opthead {
  font-size: 32px;
  font-weight: 700;
  color: #14e3d8;
  margin-top: 80px;
  padding: 0 !important;
}

.optwraptitle {
  height: 113px !important;
  max-width: 320px !important;
}

.optwrap {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative !important;
  vertical-align: top !important;
  float: left;
  padding: 0;
}

.opt-result {
  position: absolute;
  font-size: 26px;
  font-weight: 700;
  float: left;
  margin-left: -50px;
  font-family: HelveticaNeueBlackCondensed !important;
}

.opt-result em {
  position: relative;
  font-size: 18px;
  color: #E40412;
  bottom: 22px;
  left: 115px;
}

.ui-state-focus {
  outline: none;
}

.bulleft,
.bulright {
  width: 8px;
  height: 8px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background: #bbb;
  position: absolute;
  top: -4px;
  z-index: 2;
}

.bulleft {
  left: -4px;
}

.bulright {
  right: -4px;
}

.fa-usd {
  color: #fff;
  line-height: 50px !important;
  vertical-align: middle !important;
  position: relative !important;
  bottom: 4px !important;
}

#slider {
  width: 80% !important;
  position: relative;
  margin: 75px auto 75px;
  z-index: 10;
}

#sliderhr {
  margin-bottom: -55px;
  margin-top: -10px
}

#amount {
  color: #222;
  border: none;
  background: none;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: -35px;
  left: -40px;
  width: 160px;
  font-weight: 700;
  font-size: 22px;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  outline: none !important;
  border: none !important;
  box-shadow: none !important;
  webkit-box-shadow: none !important;
}

#slider-min,
#slider-max {
  position: absolute;
  top: -55px;
  font-weight: 300;
  font-size: 15px;
  color: #999;
}

#slider-min {
  left: -30px;
}

#slider-max {
  right: -45px;
}

#slider.ui-slider-horizontal {
  height: 1px;
  border: none;
  background: #bbb;
}

#slider.ui-slider-handle {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 90;
}

#slider.ui-state-default,
#slider.ui-widget-content .ui-state-default,
#slider.ui-widget-header .ui-state-default {
  border-radius: 50% !important;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 32px;
  line-height: 45px;
  text-shadow: 2px 1px 0 #444 !important;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  top: -0.9em;
  cursor: pointer;
  border: 3px solid #bbb;
  background-image: none !important;
  background: #d2000b !important;
  background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, from(#fa0011), to(#d2000b)) !important;
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #fa0011, #d2000b) !important;
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #fa0011, #d2000b) !important;
  background: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #fa0011, #d2000b) !important;
  background: -o-linear-gradient(top, #fa0011, #d2000b) !important;
}

#slider .ui-state-focus {
  border: 3px solid #bbb !important;
}

#slider .ui-state-hover {
  border-color: #555 !important;
}

#slidertitlewrap {
  margin: 0 !important;
  padding: 0 !important;
  text-align: center !important;
}

#slidertitle {
  font-size: 32px;
  font-weight: 400 !important;
  color: #222;
  margin: 0 !important;
  padding: 0 !important;
}

#slidertitle strong {
  color: #E40412;
}

#sliderpro {
  font-size: 36px;
  font-weight: 700;
  color: #14e3d8;
  margin: 0 !important;
  padding: 0 !important;
}
/* Slider End */
/* Contact Form Start */

.cont {
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #fff;
  line-height: .1em;
  margin: 70px 0 50px;
}

.contus {
  background: #222;
  padding: 0 10px;
  color: #fff
}

.round {
  border-radius: 5px;
}

.ta {
  width: 300px;
  height: 100px;
}

.sub {
  padding: 10px 30px;
  background-color: #e41420;
}

.rast {
  color: #e41420;
}

.contable {}

.contwrap {
  width: 90%;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
/* Contact Form End */
/* Accordion Start */

.wrap {
  white-space: normal;
}

#insidecont1 {
  width: 50%;
  vertical-align: top;
}

#insidecont2 {
  width: 50%;
  vertical-align: top;
}

.acccontainer div {
  white-space: nowrap;
  width: 100%;
  height: 600px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

#accordion {
  vertical-align: top;
  white-space: nowrap;
  display: inline-block;
  margin-top: 80px;
  margin-left: 275px;
}

#accordion2 {
  vertical-align: top;
  white-space: nowrap;
  display: inline-block;
  margin-top: -600px;
  margin-left: -275px;
}

#accordion article {
  z-index: 3;
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: show;
  -webkit-transform: perspective(900px) rotateY(60deg);
  -webkit-transition: all 0.7s ease-in-out;
  -moz-transform: perspective (900px) rotatey (60deg);
  -moz-transition: all 0.7s ease-in-out;
  -ms-transform: perspective(900px) rotateY(60deg);
  -ms-transition: all 0.7s ease-in-out;
  -o-transform: perspective(900px) rotateY(60deg);
  -o-transition: all 0.7s ease-in-out;
  transform: perspective(900px) rotatey(60deg);
  transition: all 0.7s ease-in-out;
  background: #fff;
  border: 1px solid #f3f3f3;
  box-shadow: 0px 5px 15px gray;
  float: left;
  height: 470px;
  margin-left: -185px;
  padding: 5px;
  width: 275px;
  position: relative;
}

#accordion2 article {
  z-index: 3;
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: show;
  -webkit-transform: perspective(900px) rotateY(-60deg);
  -webkit-transition: all 0.7s ease-in-out;
  -moz-transform: perspective(900px) rotatey(-60deg);
  -moz-transition-duration: all 0.7s ease-in-out;
  -ms-transform: perspective(900px) rotateY(-60deg);
  -ms-transition: all 0.7s ease-in-out;
  -o-transform: perspective(900px) rotateY(-60deg);
  -o-transition: all 0.7s ease-in-out;
  transform: perspective(900px) rotatey(-60deg);
  transition: all 0.7s ease-in-out;
  background: #fff;
  border: 1px solid #f3f3f3;
  box-shadow: 0px 5px 15px gray;
  float: right;
  height: 470px;
  margin-right: -185px;
  padding: 5px;
  width: 275px;
  position: relative;
}

#accordion article:first-child {
  white-space: nowrap;
  left: 0;
}

#accordion2 article:first-child {
  white-space: nowrap;
  right: 0;
}

#accordion article img {
  float: left;
  padding: 2px 10px 5px 2px;
}

#accordion2 article img {
  float: right;
  padding: 2px 10px 5px 2px;
}

#accordion article:hover {
  z-index: 5;
  white-space: nowrap;
  -webkit-transform: perspective(0) rotateY(-10deg);
  -moz-transform: rotatey(-10deg);
  -ms-transform: perspective(0) rotatey(-10deg);
  -o-transform: perspective(0) rotatey(-10deg);
  transform: rotatey(-10deg);
  margin: 0 140px 0 -60px;
}

#accordion2 article:hover {
  z-index: 5;
  white-space: nowrap;
  -webkit-transform: perspective(0) rotateY(10deg);
  -moz-transform: rotatey(10deg);
  -ms-transform: perspective(0) rotatey(10deg);
  -o-transform: perspective(0) rotatey(10deg);
  transform: rotatey(10deg);
  margin: 0 -60px 0 140px;
}
/* Accordion End */
/* Media Start */

#video1 {
  display: block;
  margin: 50px 0 !important;
  float: left;
  position: relative;
  padding: 0 20px;
}

#vidtext {
  display: block;
  margin: auto;
  position: relative;
}

.video-container {
  position: relative;
  padding-bottom: 56.25%;
  padding-top: 30px;
  height: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.video-container iframe,
.video-container object,
.video-container embed {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.redbox:hover {
  opacity: .7;
  z-index: 2;
  position: absolute;
}

.redbox {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 4;
  height: 400px;
}

.redboxbg {
  height: 330px;
  width: 320px;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1;
  background-color: #e41420;
}

.titleover {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 5;
  bottom: 175px;
  left: 140px;
  background-color: #7c7c7c;
  padding: 5px;
  pointer-events: none;
}

.titleovera {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 5;
  bottom: 175px;
  left: 110px;
  background-color: #7c7c7c;
  padding: 5px;
  pointer-events: none;
}

.overtext {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 3;
  left: 160px;
  bottom: 130px;
  pointer-events: none;
}
/* Media End */
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <!-- The above 3 meta tags *must* come first in the head; any other head content must come *after* these tags -->
  <title>Bootstrap 101 Template</title>

  <!-- Bootstrap -->
  <link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <link href="css/custom.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.3/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.3.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">

  <!-- HTML5 shim and Respond.js for IE8 support of HTML5 elements and media queries -->
  <!-- WARNING: Respond.js doesn't work if you view the page via file:// -->
  <!--[if lt IE 9]>
      <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/html5shiv/3.7.2/html5shiv.min.js"></script>
      <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/respond/1.4.2/respond.min.js"></script>
    <![endif]-->
  <style>
    .box {
      background-color: #d3d3d3;
      border: 1px solid grey;
    }
    
    body {
      padding-top: 70px;
    }
    
    .navbar-nav > li > a,
    .navbar-brand {
      padding-top: 4px !important;
      padding-bottom: 0 !important;
      height: 70px;
      vertical-align: bottom;
    }
    
    .navbar {
      min-height: 70px !important;
    }
    
    .navbar-nav li a {
      line-height: 60px;
    }
  </style>

</head>

<body>
  <div class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top">
    <div class="container">
      <div class="navbar-header">
        <a class="navbar-brand navbar-left" href="#">
          <span style="display:inline; color:#e41420; font-weight:500; padding:0; margin:0;"><img src="http://proflatfee.com/website/agent_zseries_files/8919/proflatfee_logo.png" height="60px">Pro Flat Fee Realty</span>
        </a>
        <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
          <span class="sr-only">Toggle Navigation</span>
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        </button>
      </div>
      <div class="collapse navbar-collapse">
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
          <li class="active">
            <a href="#">Home</a
                    </li>
                    <li class="dropdown">
                        <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false" data-hover="dropdown">Selling <span class="caret"></span></a>
            <ul class="dropdown-menu">
              <li><a href="#">3 Ways To Save</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Instant Home Value</a></li>
            </ul>
          </li>
          <li class="dropdown">
            <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false" data-hover="dropdown">Find A Home <span class="caret"></span></a>
            <ul class="dropdown-menu">
              <li><a href="#">Buying</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Featured Listings</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Search Homes</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">VIP Home Find</a></li>
            </ul>
          </li>
          <li class="dropdown">
            <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false" data-hover="dropdown">About <span class="caret"></span></a>
            <ul class="dropdown-menu">
              <li><a href="#">About Us</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Referrals</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Contacts</a></li>
            </ul>
          </li>
          <li class="dropdown">
            <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false" data-hover="dropdown">Resources <span class="caret"></span></a>
            <ul class="dropdown-menu">
              <li><a href="#">F.A.Q.s</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Calculators</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Buyer Reports</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Real Estate News</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Real Estate Glossary</a></li>
            </ul>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div id="carousel-example-generic" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
    <!-- Wrapper for slides -->
    <div class="carousel-inner">
      <div class="item active">
        <img src="http://www.cjhitch.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/07/city.png" alt="...">
        <div class="carousel-caption">
          <h3></h3>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="item">
        <img src="http://www.cjhitch.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/07/family.png" alt="...">
        <div class="carousel-caption">
          <h3></h3>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="item">
        <img src="http://www.cjhitch.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/07/kitchen.png" alt="...">
        <div class="carousel-caption">
          <h3></h3>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="item">
        <img src="http://www.cjhitch.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/07/multipledoors.png" alt="...">
        <div class="carousel-caption">
          <h3></h3>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="item">
        <img src="http://www.cjhitch.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/07/homewithflag.png" alt="...">
        <div class="carousel-caption">
          <h3></h3>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="item">
        <img src="http://www.cjhitch.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/07/homefront.png" alt="...">
        <div class="carousel-caption">
          <h3></h3>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    </a>
  </div>
  <!-- Carousel -->
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div id="slidertitlewrap">
      <p id="slidertitle" class="allcaps">
        </br>here are <strong>3 ways</strong> to save with</p>
      <h2 id="sliderpro" class="smallcaps">PRO Flat Fee Realty</h2>
      <p class="allcaps">(SLIDE THE DOLLAR SIGN AND WATCH THE SAVINGS BELOW)</p>
    </div>
    <div>

      <div id="slider" class="ui-slider ui-slider-horizontal ui-widget ui-widget-content ui-corner-all">

        <i class="bulleft"></i>
        <i class="bulright"></i>
        <div id="slider-min">

          $100,000

        </div>
        <div id="slider-max">

          $2,000,000

        </div>
        <div class="ui-slider-range ui-widget-header ui-corner-all ui-slider-range-min"></div>
        <span class="ui-slider-handle ui-state-default ui-corner-all div-cover" tabindex="0">

       <input id="amount" type="text" readonly=""></input>
    </span>

      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <hr id="sliderhr">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-4">
        <div class="optwrap">
          <div class="optwraptitle">
            <h2 class="allcaps opthead">Option 1</h2>
            <h3 class="smallcaps opttitle">Another Realtor Brings Buyer</h3>
          </div>
          <div class="opt-result">
            <span class="allcaps"><em>Your</em>Savings</span>
            <input id="result1" class="result" readonlytype="text" value="$5,451" />
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-4">
        <div class="optwrap">
          <div class="optwraptitle">
            <h2 class="allcaps opthead">Option 2</h2>
            <h3 class="smallcaps opttitle">PRO Flat Fee Represents Buyer</h3></div>
          <div class="opt-result"><span class="allcaps"><em>Your</em>Savings</span>
            <input id="result2" class="result" readonlytype="text" value="$9,701" />
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-4">
        <div class="optwrap">
          <div class="optwraptitle">
            <h2 class="allcaps opthead">Option 3</h2>
            <h3 class="smallcaps opttitle">Owner Finds Buyer</h3>
          </div>
          <div class="opt-result">
            <span class="allcaps"><em>your</em>savings</span>
            <input id="result3" class="result" readonlytype="text" value="$11,201" />
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <!-- jQuery (necessary for Bootstrap's JavaScript plugins) -->
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <!-- Include all compiled plugins (below), or include individual files as needed -->
  <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <script src="js/slider.js"></script>
  <script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.3/jquery-ui.js"></script>
  <script src="js/bootstrap-hover-dropdown.min.js"></script>
  <script src="js/jquery.ui.touch-punch.min.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Sorry the markup is long, but I wanted to include everything, in case someone sees something I am missing. It isn't working obviously without the external links, but you can see it in action on the website I posted above.

Please don't remove tags, that only you deem not relevant. When I am asking a question about mobile platforms, Iphone, is on the iOS platform. it seems quite stupid to remove the tag relating to it.

Comment: Try to control the width of your inputs with the class `.result`. e.g. give it a certain max-width with media-queries for smaller resolutions.

Comment: I assumed, you literally meant "<"input">" so I looked and it was missing from one. It did not work unfortunately. The screen for a split second will start filling the entire mobile screen. After that it resizes itself and fills only half, while the navbar at the top continues to fill the entire thing.

Comment: Well in that case I would advice that you start by cleaning up your code. You have a lot of errors, like missing end tags. Your inputs also have an attribute `readonlytype`, which doesn't exist in the specs. After your code validates without errors, have a look again at your css.

Comment: Thank you for that suggestion. I actually did figure it out late last evening and I was going to remove this question. The "textareas" for the results of the input were close to 600px wide. Even though it was just showing whitespace, it rendered on the screen. Thank you for pointing out some of the other issues. I had an open tag which ended up generating an extra as a result, and was using some deprecated practices as well, which validator pointed out.